# Element wise evaluation of symbolic functions in Matlab

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math

I have a vector of symbolic expressions and a vector of points. I then want to obtain a vector, where 1st element is the first symbolic function evaluated at the first point, second - value of the second function at the second point etc. I can do this with the 'for' loop like this

```
>> syms x
>> f=formula([x, x^2, x^3]);
>> a=[1, 2, 3];
>> ans=zeros(1,3);
>> for i=1:3
z(x)=f(i);
ans(i)=z(a(i));
end
>> ans
ans =
     1     4    27
```

But is there a way to avoid loops? Some kind of element-wise evaluation?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an additional answer to your question, supposing that we had to use the symbolic math toolbox instead.  First, create your formula as normal:

```
syms x
f = formula([x, x^2, x^3);
```

You can then use `subs` to substitute values of `x` with values that you want.  `subs` has syntax like so:

```
out = subs(f, val);
```

`val` can be a single value, vector or matrix of values that you wish to substitute the variables in your formula with.  If you want to use a vector, it's important that you specify this as a **column vector**.  You'll see why later.

The crux behind this is that for each value of `x` you want to use for substituting, it will replace the **entire** formula with `x`.  In other words, if you did `out = subs(f, [1;2;3]);`, this will output a matrix where the first row consists of `x=1`, the next row consists of `x=2` and the last row consists of `x=3`.  If you did `out = subs(f,[1 2 3]);`, this will give you a `9 x 1` vector, where each trio of three is the output for that particular `x` value.

This isn't exactly what you want, but you can simply choose all of the elements along the **diagonal** when you specify the input as a column vector as your output, as this would exactly correspond the `i'th` entry of the element in your vector with the `i'th` formula.

In other words:

```
A = (1:3).';
out = subs(f, A)

out =

[ 1, 1,  1]
[ 2, 4,  8]
[ 3, 9, 27]

finalOut = diag(out)

finalOut =

  1
  4
 27
```

This is really the only way I can see this without using a `for` loop.  Bear in mind that this is only for a single vector.  If you want the actual `double` values instead of it being represented as `sym`, you'll need to cast the output using `double()`.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I wanted! I tried `subs` before, but it gave me what you have described with too many outputs. The last step with `diag` indeed finishes the job perfectly! Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 0):

First off, let's avoid using the symbolic math toolbox for this.  It's unnecessary.  Try making your `formula` accept vectorized inputs.  If I understand your question, in general you would like to take in a **matrix** where the first column applies `x`, the second column applies `x^2` and the third column applies `x^3`.  In other words, do this:

```
f = @(x) [x(:,1), x(:,2).^2, x(:,3).^3];
```

This is known as an [anonymous function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html).  Simply put, it will return a function for you stored in `f` that will do what we just described above.  What this function will do is it will take the first column of the matrix, and simply output `x`.  The second column of the matrix will output those values but squared and the last column of the matrix will output those values but cubed.  Now, provide a matrix where each *row* corresponds to the values you want to evaluate for each element in `f`.

Example:

```
A = [1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9]

A =

 1     2     3
 4     5     6
 7     8     9
```

Now, simply use `A` as input into `f`.

```
result = f(A)

result =

 1     4    27
 4    25   216
 7    64   729
```

The first row evaluates your formula at `[1,2,3]`, the next row evaluates your formula at `[4,5,6]` and so on.

Your example only provided this for one row, but this code here generalizes to an `N x 3` matrix.

## Note

This will only work if your matrix has 3 columns.  If you try to do anything more, you'll get an index out of bounds error... which makes sense as your formula was only defined for three inputs at a time.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the suggestion. However in my case functions inside `formula` are much more complicated (I put `x`, `x^2`, `x^3` just for simplicity - to show what I want in the end). These functions were obtained over some (non trivial) symbolic operations and I don't know these functions in advance (and can't compute by hand), therefore I can't define the anonymous function as you described. But yes, I'm looking exactly for something like '`.^`' for symbolic functions.

Comment: OK, that isn't a problem.  I'll just make a new post!